# Passport Registration Error with user.login

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am getting an undefined function error when trying to log a user in after creating their account via Mongoose...

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at /node_modules/passport/lib/passport/http/request.js:44:48
at pass (/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/index.js:240:14)
at Passport.serializeUser (/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/index.js:242:5)
at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/http/request.js:43:29)
at Promise.<anonymous> (/routes/index.js:33:25)
at Promise.addBack (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:120:8)
```

My register function in routes/index.js looks like this:

```
exports.register = function (req, res) {
// Generate salt
Common.bcrypt.genSalt(function(err, salt) {
    req.body.salt = salt;
    // Generate hash
    Common.bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, function(error, hash) {
        req.body.hash = hash;
        // Remove clear text password
        delete req.body.password;
        // Save new user
        new Model.User(req.body).save(function(err, user) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(req);
            if (user) {
                req.login(user);
                req.redirect('/');
            } else {
                res.json(false);
            }
        });

    });
 });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at `node_modules/passport/lib/passport/http/request.js`, line 44 column 48 you will see that the function `done` is being invoked. The error tells you that `undefined is not a function`, so `done` is not defined. If you look on line 29 of the same file, you will see that `done` is a parameter you are supposed to pass to the `req.login` function. In other words, it's expecting a callback and you are not providing one. Maybe something like this:

```
if (user) {
  req.login(user, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return req.send('FAILBOAT!');
    }
    return req.redirect('/');
  });
}
```

While I use passport, I don't call `req.login` directly so I'm not 100% certain on the implications of the code above. I'll also point out that I do all of the bcrypt stuff in my user model, which seems like a cleaner way to approach that aspect of the problem.

Comment: That seemed to fix those errors, but now it says Login Failed: Error: failed to serialize user into session.

Session serialization works fine when I am just logging in, but when I call the req.login method it has a problem serializing. Any ideas?

Comment: I am using this in my app.js:

passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb){ cb(null, user.id) });

Comment: I accepted your answer - I found out that when Mongoose returns the save, it is not giving me the id of the record so I will need to figure out how to get it to spit that back to me.

Comment: Fair enough. Can I ask why are you directly calling `req.login` in the first place? I didn't see that mentioned in the [guide](http://passportjs.org/guide/).

Comment: I got it all working - sweet. Thanks for your help. I am calling that after a user creates an account using the local strategy. After they create their account, it automatically logs them in instead of forcing them to type their login/pass again.

Comment: Scott can you please post your solution? I am having same problem

Comment: This works for me except I used res.redirect when successful.